# Extract second word from a file in yum repository file using command line or bash

Tags: linux, bash, rpm, yum

I wanted to extract a paticular file path from a text file (yum repository file) The file contents looks like this

```
[rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms]
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)
baseurl = https://myhost.com
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
sslverify = 1
sslclientkey = /etc/pki/entitlement/60472949067-key.pem
sslclientcert = /etc/pki/entitlement/604712349067.pem
metadata_expire = 1
enabled_metadata = 1

[rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms]
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)
baseurl = https://myhost.com
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
sslverify = 1
sslclientkey = /etc/pki/entitlement/6047297349067-key.pem
sslclientcert = /etc/pki/entitlement/6047297349067.pem
metadata_expire = 1
enabled_metadata = 1
```

My requirement is to extract sslclinetkey path of both rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpm and rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpm through the command line or script

Any help would be appreciated

*UPDATE*

I tried this way, but I am getting multiple entries

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo  | grep sslclientkey | awk '{print $3}'
/etc/pki/entitlement/2627848977587647846-key.pem
/etc/pki/entitlement/7675461792121821585-key.pem
/etc/pki/entitlement/3236342435348109549-key.pem
/etc/pki/entitlement/60472974412349067-key.pem
/etc/pki/entitlement/3236342435348109549-key.pem
/etc/pki/entitlement/60472974412349067-key.pem
```

But I only need of rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpm and rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpm

Comment: The `grep` does not make sense. You have to read sequentially through the file, and once you recognize a certain section, you pick the next filename inside this section. Think about this problem on how you would solve it in any other programming language (C, Perl, whatever you are familiar with). The idea is the same with bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F' = ' '/sslclientcert/{print $2}' file 
# or 
awk '/sslclientcert/{print $3}' file 

/etc/pki/entitlement/604712349067.pem
/etc/pki/entitlement/6047297349067.pem

awk -F' = ' '/\[.*\]/ {printf "%s ", $1} /sslclientcert/{print $2}' file 
[rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms] /etc/pki/entitlement/604712349067.pem
[rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms] /etc/pki/entitlement/6047297349067.pem
```

Comment: awk -F' = ' '/\[.*\]/ {printf "%s ", $1} /sslclientcert/{print $2}' this did the trick! Cheers mate

Comment: This should do the job, too: `awk '/sslclientkey/{print $3}'`

Comment: @Cyrus : This would not check for the specific rpm-section he wants to look at.

Answer (score 1):

It is just ini file. So crudini will do the work:

```
crudini --get /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms sslclientkey
```

or for all sections:

```
for i in in `crudini --get /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo`; do
  crudini --get /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo "$i" sslclientkey
done
```